# Play video in full screen with USB Audio

Tags: audio, video

I am using Rasbian...

Is there any way I can play video in full screen with audio on my USB headphones?

I can play fullscreen using `omxplayer`, but audio cannot be redirected to USB as omxplayer uses OpenMAX as per [this](https://github.com/huceke/omxplayer/issues/36) thread.

I can play using `mplayer` with USB audio, but it won't show in full screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: I will check it when I get home, but couldn't you use the VLC player? To download, type `sudo apt-get vlc`

Comment: @xxmbabanexx VLC won't play in Raspi under Raspian.

Comment: Wait... but I have used VLC in raspbian... are you also using xmbc?

Comment: @xxmbabanexx I am using Wheezy raspian. Vlc won't show the video when I tried playing.

Comment: In what format is the video?

Comment: @xxmbabanexx It is avi. I tried increasing the GPU split.  Now it plays in window mode, but not full screen.

Answer (score 1):

> I can play using `mplayer` with USB audio, but it won't show in full screen.

If you use the `-fs` option, mplayer will play in full screen mode. For example, `mplayer -fs mymovie.avi`.

Also, if you press `f`, mplayer will maximize the video to full screen.

Try `man mplayer` for some more keyboard commands and options.

Comment: It will become fullscreen, but the video will still be playing as a small window in the middle.